# Runtime node version is different than what node -v returns - husky can't run git hooks

Tags: git, npm, phpstorm

```
Husky requires Node 10 (runtime: v8.10.0), can't run Git hook.
```

node -v: v12.20.1
sudo node -v: v8.10.0

Anyone know how to remedy this or what is actually going on? I'm not able to use git at all from phpstorm because of this.

Comment: You can do something like this: `env | grep '^PATH='` with and without `sudo` to see what your `$PATH` is defined as, for your user and as root. It could just be a matter of modifying it.

Comment: Must be a `$PATH` issue; what OS is it, does the hook work if you start the IDE from terminal?

Comment: @roryrjb what would a modification look like? I'm not exactly sure what I'd modify- they look the same though

Comment: @lena yes, it does work when I start from the terminal. for my own knowledge's sake, why is this?

Comment: @JimmyBlundell when you say they look the same, are they in the same order? The kind of thing I was thinking of is that the `$PATH` that is available to your user defines the "custom" location of node 12 and with root it doesn't and just falls back to a standard location such as `/usr/bin`. You could also check with `which` where they are, i.e. `which node` and `sudo which node`. You may have to add the directory of Node 12 to `/etc/environment` as the first part of the `$PATH`, e.g. `PATH=/path/to/node12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When being launched from desktop/System menu/Toolbox, WebStorm only sees environment variables configured in login shell, but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`), so the environment (including `$PATH`) is different from the one you have in terminal. Possible solutions:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell by moving them to the corresponding shell profile config
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal to make it inherit terminal environment

see also [IDEABKL-7589](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589)